# CSS doesn't load

Tags: css

Example:

This is my simple HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>

    <section id="left"> Put an image anywhere in this box.</section>
    <section id="right"> </section>

    <img id="tree" src="file:///home/john/Desktop/javascripts%20basics           /ashtree.jpg">
</body>

<footer>
    <script src="john.js"></script>
    <link href="john.css" text="text/css" rel="stylesheets.css">
</footer>

</html>
```

This is my simple CSS document:

```
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 3px solid green;
}
```

The HTML loads in my firefox web-browser, but the css does not.I downloaded chromium as well and it doest work either. Ive checked many examples and I think I got it right. The question is...where do I look next to solve this problem. I have no clue where to start as I am not very educated with computers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that actually describes the question you're asking or problem you're having. It should describe things in a way that will have meaning to a future reader seeing it in a list of search results. Your level of experience or complaining about it being difficult isn't going to provide any useful information. Thanks.

Comment: Google 'HTML/CSS bootcamp'. Even if you found a solution for this problem, you will not be able to continue without properly going through a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You weren't kidding around. You really are getting your ass kicked by stupid stuff.

It looks like you haven't linked in you stylesheet properly You need to link it in your `<head>` section - it won't work in the footer. Even if you moved what you have in your footer to your `<head>` it is malformed.

[Take a look at this example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="john.css">
</head>
```